# Loading MySQL dump with different table type

Tags: mysql, backup, database

Suppose I have an SQL dump, how do I load this into a fresh mySQL installation...as **innodb**?

Comment: ensure you mysqldump --order-by-primary [key] in order to save index space (InnoDB and MyISAM index very differently) and that you really want to do this http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/01/12/should-you-move-from-myisam-to-innodb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql <database name> -u root -p < file.sql
```

Then just alter the tables you want to change to innodb

```
> alter table <foo> set engine=innodb;
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on rodjek's answer, you can't decide what engine to use on the command line; your SQL dump must *already* have the engine type set correctly.  You can edit the existing dump file, however, and change any instances of `ENGINE=MyISAM` (or, really, any `ENGINE` statement that doesn't specify `InnoDB`) and change it to `ENGINE=InnoDB`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll have to edit the .sql file. At the end of each CREATE TABLE stanza is an ENGINE definition. Right now, I'd guess this says ENGINE=MyISAM. Change this to InnoDB for each table, save the file, then import.

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
…
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: This will work if carefully carried out, but (depending on the size of the DB) it may be a *large* file you have to edit, with *very long* lines of INSERT statements.

Comment: True, though I've overcome this many times in the past by making judicious use of regex search/replace in vim. Any decent text editor should be able to do the same.

Comment: You can simplify things by creating separate dumps for the structure and the data. Then just edit the structure file(s) and import that before importing the data.